# finding both "Shopping_mall" and "food" within single URL for google places API

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I tried following URLs to get both "shopping_mall" and "food" within a single request.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%@,%@&radius=1500&sensor=true&key=%@&types=shopping_mall|food
```

This gives me response with only "food" type of places.

But,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%@,%@&radius=1500&sensor=true&key=%@&types=shopping_mall
```

Gives the result with "shopping_mall" only. Also, The same URL with "food" only give the result same as "shopping_mall|food".

Has anyone faced this issue. I have searched across but cannot find any useful answer to that.

P.S. I have gone through this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests) and this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html) , too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting only food in the first request, and you're getting 20 results, then it is likely Google believes the most relevant results are food. You may have to do 2 requests. You can try adding keyword=shopping, but that may limit your food results.