# google-place-api returning null json

Tags: android, google-places-api

in my app i want to use google place api to get nearest places such as atm, bus stand etc...
but it returning null result.. url is

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=28.568315675,77.33492885&radius=5000&types=ATM&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAryW3R30sFQCsDb3wQR_EeiZ_dAvyUilQ

and code is::

```
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);                



            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                


            urlConnection.connect();                


            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
```

i hv reffered to many links but no koi help milii....

[How can I search places with specific types using Google Places API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652543/how-can-i-search-places-with-specific-types-using-google-places-api)

[finding both "Shopping_mall" and "food" within single URL for google places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173716/finding-both-shopping-mall-and-food-within-single-url-for-google-places-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you r using key i.e key for android apps.. instead of key for browser app.. use dis.. it will definitely run... gud luck